# Synapse spark job fails as input folder does not exist

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse

How to do exception handling for file reading.

For example, I have a daily job that will run at 8:00 am. It reads files from Azure data lake storage(Gen 2). The path looks like 2022/01/06/data.csv. So the file will not be populated in ADLS for all the days. So whenever the file is not populated the job is getting failed. So I tried using try-catch to handle the exception. Is there any other way to handle the exception?

```
df1 = spark.read.format('csv').load(fileLocation)
```

Comment: Could you show what `fileLocation` looks like and the full error?

Comment: You could call it via a Synapse Pipeline, use the Get Metadata activity and Exists operation to check the file exists - do it that way?  I can write up an example if that sounds like it would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize your problem: The spark-job is failing because the folder you are pointing to does not exist.

On Azure Synapse, [mssparkutils](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-scala) is perfect for this. This is how you would do it in Scala (you can do similar for python as well). This works for notebooks as well as spark/pyspark batch jobs.

```scala
  def exists(f: String): Boolean = {
    try {
      mssparkutils.fs.ls(f)
      true
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => false
    }
  }


exists("valid/folder") // returns true
exists("abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/valid/folder") // returns true

exists("invalid/folder") //returns false
exists("abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/invalid/folder") // returns false

// you can also do below for more info:
mssparkutils.fs.help()
```

If the storage account is not your primary linked storage account, you would need to provide the full url (abfss path).

I prefer providing full-fledged url (abfss path) as synapse account can have multiple linked storage accounts. So there is no scope for error